# How do I accept a tokenized input into Select2 (i.e. User pasted options) using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, tokenize, jquery-select2-4

I am using Select2 in a .NET MVC website to allow users to easily search and select items in a form.  This currently works fine however my users have asked if they can have a way of pasting a list of items into the box, instead of searching and selecting them one by one.

I have found information about the Select2 `tokenizer` parameter which allows overloading the default tokenizer with a custom one.  However most examples I've found target older versions of Select2 and I am using version 4.0.

How can I allow pasted lists of tokens using ajax to resolve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is how I have implemented this.  Each token that is separated with either a `,` or `;` is searched using the Ajax method already defined and the first result returned is used.

```
$("…").select2({
    …
    tokenizer: function (input, s2, callback) {
        var term = input.term;
        if (term.indexOf(',') < 0 && term.indexOf(';') < 0)
            return input; // Exit if no tokens

        var parts = term.split(/,|;/);
        for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            var part = parts[i].trim();
            if (part.length > 2) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: s2.options.ajax.url,
                    dataType: s2.options.ajax.dataType,
                    data: s2.options.ajax.data({ term: part }),
                    async: false, // If async then unable to return unmatched tokens
                    success: function (data) {
                        var pr = s2.options.ajax.processResults(data, { term: part });
                        callback(pr.results[0]);
                        parts.splice(i--, 1);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return { term: parts.join(';') }; // Rejoin unmatched tokens
    },
    …
});
```